# Inline aligment for input label in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, alignment, shinydashboard

I want to have my `numericInputIcon` labels inline with the input boxes, and at the same time have the labels like the main and sub categories :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML("div#inline label { width: 52%; }
                               div#inline input { display: inline-block; width: 68%;}"))),
      tags$head(
        tags$style(type="text/css", "#inline label{ display: table-cell; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; }
                                   #inline .form-group { display: table-row;}")),

      box(
        title = "Shiny Box",
        status = "success",
        solidHeader = TRUE,

        div(id="inline",  style="width:35vw;",
            div(HTML("<b>TEST </b>")),
            br(),
            column(12,
                   numericInputIcon("A", h5("test1"), value = 20, icon = icon("percent"))) ,
            column(12,offset = 1,
                   numericInputIcon("B", h5("test1A"), value = 40, icon = icon("percent")) ,
                   numericInputIcon("C", h5("test1AA"), value = 60, icon = icon("percent"))) ,
            column(12,
                   numericInputIcon("D", h5("test2"), value = 20, icon = icon("percent"))) ,
            column(12,offset = 1,
                   numericInputIcon("E", h5("test2A"), value = 40, icon = icon("percent")) ,
                   numericInputIcon("F", h5("test2AA"), value = 60, icon = icon("percent"))) ,
            currencyInput("X", "Total", value = 0.3, format = "percentageUS2dec")
            
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

How should I correct the code to have all the input boxes aligned in one column ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `offset` add a class to the subcategory `h5` tags which could be used to set the left margin for the label without affecting the placement of the input box. In the code below I added a class `indent` and set left margin via `h5.indent {margin-left: 40px}`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML("div#inline label { width: 52%; }
                               div#inline input { display: inline-block; width: 68%;}"))),
      tags$head(
        tags$style(type="text/css", 
                   "
                   #inline label{ display: table-cell; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; }
                   #inline .form-group { display: table-row;}
                   h5.indent {margin-left: 40px}
                   ")),
      
      box(
        title = "Shiny Box",
        status = "success",
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        
        div(id="inline",  style="width:35vw;",
            div(HTML("<b>TEST </b>")),
            br(),
            column(12,
                   numericInputIcon("A", h5("test1"), value = 20, icon = icon("percent"))) ,
            column(12,
                   numericInputIcon("B", h5("test1A", class = 'indent'), value = 40, icon = icon("percent")) ,
                   numericInputIcon("C", h5("test1AA", class = 'indent'), value = 60, icon = icon("percent"))) ,
            column(12,
                   numericInputIcon("D", h5("test2"), value = 20, icon = icon("percent"))) ,
            column(12,
                   numericInputIcon("E", h5("test2A", class = 'indent'), value = 40, icon = icon("percent")) ,
                   numericInputIcon("F", h5("test2AA", class = 'indent'), value = 60, icon = icon("percent"))) ,
            currencyInput("X", "Total", value = 0.3, format = "percentageUS2dec")
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

[image]

Comment: I was just about to post this same solution (of course with a different class name and different `margin-left`) XD.